# How to prevent the accidental deletion of a file but give write permission

Tags: linux, shell

I have a status file called `DBStatus.log` in Linux and I want to prevent it from accidental deletion. I tried with `chattr -a filename`, but when I try to write to that file using the script, it's giving an error like `E212: Can't open file for writing.`

Can you please suggest me how to prevent deletion of the file but give write permission.
The current permissions are `-rw-rw-r--`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a programming question. You might do better asking on [unix.se] but check their help centre before you post.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'prevent deletion'.  In classic Unix-like systems, if you mean "cannot remove the file name from the directory", then make sure the directory is not writable.  If you mean "cannot erase the contents of the file", then there isn't a way to make a file writable and not erasable.  Looking at `chattr`, more options are available.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `then there isn't a way to make a file writable and not erasable` <-- SELinux might do the job. However, write protecting the directory might be already what the OP want.

Comment: @hek2mgl: `chattr` has a bunch of options, include `-a` for 'append only'.  There's also an `lsattr` command.  Classic Unix isn't sufficient any more (more's the pity).  The OP should try `chattr +a DBStatus.log` to make it append-only; the `-a` removes the append-only status.

Comment: My exact requirement is  checking the DB connection in the interval of 30 min, If the DB connection fails then DBStatus.log file will contain failure else it will be success. Based on the DBStatus.log file we are restarting the applications if DBComes back after the failure. So i want to prevent the deletion of the DBStatus.log but make it writable by the script.

Comment: Then, as Jonathan said above, remove write permission from the directory containing your log file.